# Read td values and display total with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I remake the question hoping that it will be better understood. I'm working on a table.php file which is structured below:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="a" name="id">Field1</td>
  <td class="b" name="title">Field2</td>
  <td class="c" name="adder">Field3</td>
  <td class="d" name="addend">Field4</td>
  <td class="e" name="sum">Field5</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to read the already given values of Field3 and Field4, make addition calculation of both numbers, and display the result in Field5 with php or javascript. I have tried this:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementByClassName("a");
var y = document.getElementByClassName("b");
var z = x+y;
document.write('z').innerHTML = c;
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
var a = document.getElementByClassName("a").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementByClassName("b").innerHTML;
var c = a+b;
document.write("c").innerHTML = c;
</script>
```

...but none of them working. Any new ideas?

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes! Give me a couple of minutes to upload a couple of thoughts.

Comment: You seem to be confusing IDs and classes.  getElementById only works on a DOM element with an id attribute.  You've only set class attributes.

Comment: I correct that. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery :

```
var tot1 = parseInt($('.a').text());
var tot2 = parseInt($('.b').text());
var tot3 = parseInt(tot1+tot2);
$('.c').text(tot3);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
var a = 0;
$('table td:not(last-child)').each(function(i) {
    a += parseInt($(this).text());
});

$('table td:last-child').text(a);
```

Hope this helps!